# Creating a dll in C++ which is used to constantly calculate maths function

Tags: c++, dll

I got a problem. I'm trying to create a dll which can calculate the distance between 2 points when i send in 2 different sets of values.
However, when I send in my 2nd set of values in, I realise my first set of values have gone missing in the array ( the array is used to store the values)

Below is my code:

```
int click = 0;   //click is used to measure the number of times i have clicked, ie to say the number of times im injecting new (a,b) points into the function below.

double MeasureDistance(double a, double b)
{
    /******* Create Array to Store The Points ********/

    /** Initializing the array **/
    double xDistance =0;
    double yDistance =0;
    double TDistance = 0;
    static double **Array;
    int column = 0; //used to toggle the column number
    int width = 100;
    int height = 100;
    Array = new double *[width];
    for (int i=0; i <width; i++)
    {
        Array [i] = new double [height];
    }

    /*** Now a and b are stored inside the Array[0][0] ***/

    for (column =0; column <2; column ++)
    {
        if ((column % 2)==0)
        {
            Array [click][column] = a; //storing at [0,0]
        }
        else 
        {   
            Array [click][column] = b; //storing at [0,1]
        }
    }
                for (int row = 2; row < click; row ++)
    {
        for (column = 0; column <2; column ++)
        {   
            if ((column % 2) == 0)
            {
                xDistance = Array [0][column] - Array [row][column];
            }
            else
            {
                yDistance = Array [0][column] - Array [row][column];
            }
        }

        TDistance = sqrt((xDistance * xDistance) + (yDistance * yDistance));
    }

/*** Clearing up of array ***/
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        delete[] Array[i];
    }
    delete[] Array;


click++;
    return TDistance ;
}
```

I realise that when I inject my 2nd set of a and b values in, my values in array [0][0] and [0][1] goes missing but my 2nd set of values are stored in [1][0] and [1][1]. Any idea how i can run this script without losing the previous values?
Thanks loads in advance. Code edited to clear some queries.

Comment: Every time you call the function, all automatic variables a reinitialized. Apart from that, you are not `deleting` your `Array` which will cause your process to starve eventually.

Comment: What's `click` in the array subscript on assignment?

Comment: @bash.d Not only are the automatic variables reinitialized, the Array will get overwritten, too, so it's no wonder the values are "gone". They're simply left in the old array and the new array is of course empty.

Comment: @arne Yes, you are right!

Answer (score 2):

With the line `Array = new double *[width];` you are initialising your array in every function call. If you need to store values (I very much doubt)  it is better to use an static initialised vector. But generaly it is a **very bad idea** to let the result of a function depend on former calls. If you realy need to accumulate state, think about creating a function object for this purpose.

*Edit:*

With a function object you can change the behavior of the algorithm with changing `operator()` and the datastructure to hold your data via member variables.

*2nd Edit:*
You probably want something like this:

```
struct MeasureDistance {
  double last_x;
  double last_y;

  MeasureDistance() : last_x(0), last_y(0) {}
  double operator()(double new_x, double new_y) {
    double diff_x=last_x-new_x;
    double diff_y=last_y-new_y;
    double result=sqrt(diff_x*diff_x,diff_y*_diff_y);

    last_x=new_x;
    last_y=new_y;

    return result;
};

MeasureDistance md;
cout 
  << md(0.0, 1.0) << '\n' //prints 1
  << md(2.0, 1.0) << '\n' //prints 2
  ;
```

Comment: -1 for recommending a static variable. Recommending an object is better, but not needed: just passing a reference to eg an std::vector< double > as extra argument to the function should do the trick

Comment: @stijn Ok I will make it more clear that it is a bad idea. But a function object is better than an extra argument. There you can change implementation without changing the interface. A look at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/accumulators.html shows how interfaces for accumulation can be implemented.

Comment: im new to C++. So i dont really get it. Is there any worked example for me to refer upon?

Comment: @user2500220 Are you trying to implement something where you push a value and get the distance to the last value?

Comment: @JanHerrmann U GOT IT! Sorry if my description was kinda bad!